# Focus on another fields without knowing it

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu

I'm doing an android app, which use configuration file to generate a formular. The fields can be multiple type of field, and for type *list*, i'm using an InstantAutoComplete. I can't use a spinner because the user should be allowed to write some text. The problem I have is that, by default, when the user select a value, the focus don't go to the next fields, and I can't use `field.requestFocus();` because I don't know what will be the next field, because they are added in a loop. I'm looking for a solution for a a long time but I can't find anything that work.

Thank you in advance et sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

You can find **currently focused** `View` in Window & then **compare** its `id` with list of `EditText`, If match found `requestFocus()` on next `EditText`.

```
    View view = getCurrentFocus();
    for (int i = 0; i < editTextList.size(); i++) {
        if (view.hasFocus() && view.getId == editTextList.get(i).getId()) {
            if ((i+1) < editTextList.size())
                editTextList.get(i+1).requestFocus();
            else
                editTextList.get(0).requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

**NOTE :** This `if ((i+1) < editTextList.size())` condition is responsible for focusing 0th element when current focus is not last `EditText` from the list.